# Trying to parse a HTML page using JSoup parser in Android?

Tags: android

So far I've tried this example which I just took from this site but it is not working in my case and I don't know why?! Is there anyone who can tell me how can I solve this problem, here is the code: this code shows me NullExceptionPointer

And i tried to print the doc.select() it shows me error :s null excetptionpointer.

```
 URL url = null;
try {
    url = new URL("http://www.nseindia.com/content/equities/niftysparks.htm");
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
Document doc = null;
try {
    doc = Jsoup.parse(url, 3000);
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Element table = doc.select("table[class=niftyd]").first();

Iterator<Element> ite = table.select("td[width=65]").iterator();

ite.next(); // first one is image, skip it

System.out.println("Value 1: " + ite.next().text());
System.out.println("Value 2: " + ite.next().text());
System.out.println("Value 3: " + ite.next().text());
System.out.println("Value 4: " + ite.next().text());
```

Any help I would really appreciate it, I'm fighting for the whole day and I cant solve it! :s

Comment: Can you please paste here your Exception log. For better answers.

Comment: If you get NullPointerException when calling doc.select, then doc is null...

Comment: Here is the LogCat error:
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RunTimeException: Unable to start a activity ComponentInfo{com.luli/....
java.lang.NullPointerException
at android.app ActivityThread.handleLauncherAcitivty(ActivityThread.java:1622)
and so on .....

Comment: @Jong the website is working and u can see the data, how can it be the doc null??? maybe my query is wrong???

Comment: I've never used JSoup so I have no idea what is this 'parse' method. Perhaps read their documentation and see when 'parse' returns null.

Comment: @Vinay what about u ?? can u help me in this case??

Comment: Can you please paste the full exception stack trace by editing your post.. Because, that will point out which line of your code is causing this..

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `doc.select("table[class=niftyd]")` returns null. When your call first on it you get the null pointer exception. You're trying to call a method on an object that is actually null. You need make sure what `doc.select()` returns isn't null.

Comment: is the problem here?? Document doc = null; and why doc.select("table[class=niftyd]") returns null till there is a table niftyd

Comment: hi bro, im able to print the doc.select("table[class=niftyd]") and it returns some html data which is no longer returning null exception but it prints some unexpected data and one line below then it returns null pointer again.